# Проверка наличия записи в таблице (перевести с типичного mysql)

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Сейчас сделано на обычном варианте mysql:

```
/* Проверка на наличие такого email уже в БД */
protected function checkEmail()
{

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `mytable` WHERE (`email`='$this->email')");

    if (!$result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        // если нету такого email в БД верни TRUE, значить можно регить новый
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // если есть такой email, то верни FALSE
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Как это проделать на **MySQLi**?

Answer (score 2):

Сам себе отвечу.

```
/* Проверка на наличие такого email уже в БД */
public function checkEmail()
{
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `email` FROM `league` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1'))
    {
        $result->bind_param("s",$this->email);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();

    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    /* close statement */
    $result->close();

    if (!$rows)
    {
        // если нету такого email в БД верни TRUE, значить можно регить новый
        return TRUE;    
    }
    else
    {
        // если есть такой email, то верни FALSE
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Делайте просто select count(...) ...